# Measurement equation of Tree-Step pathway model

Tags: biochemistry, theoretical-biology

I am not specialist in biology but I want to test a parameters estimation method (based on Kalman filter) on the Tree-Step pathway model, but I cannot find a document that gives the measurement equation of the Three-Step Pathway model (Moles et all 2003, Parameter Estimation in Biochemical Pathways: A Comparison of Global Optimization Methods"), can someone give me some references?